# Unable to analyse XML file with SonarQube (sonar.scanner)

Tags: xml, windows, xpath, sonarqube

I am new to Sonarqube and this is my first try at analyzing one informatica XML through Sonar Scanner.
I have created project and also provided one small rule in it (by providing the XPATH query).

The XPATH query is working properly when tried in a sample tool.
However, in Sonarqube when running sonar-scanner it is giving the below error:

furnishing below the error which I received while running the below command:

`C:\sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778-windows\bin>sonar-scanner -X`

**Error**:

```
   Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
    org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: 
    Unable to analyse file C:/sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778-windows/bin/s_m_GW_FDR_SOI_ST_SPCIF_PL.XML
```

Note: Apologies if I have missed anything as I am new to this.

```html
13:12:57.798 INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778-windows\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
13:12:57.809 INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
13:12:57.830 INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.0.3.778
13:12:57.832 INFO: Java 1.8.0_121 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
13:12:57.834 INFO: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
13:12:57.991 DEBUG: keyStore is :
13:12:57.993 DEBUG: keyStore type is : jks
13:12:57.999 DEBUG: keyStore provider is :
13:12:58.001 DEBUG: init keystore
13:12:58.012 DEBUG: init keymanager of type SunX509
13:12:58.264 INFO: User cache: C:\Users\p.das.purkayastha\.sonar\cache
13:12:58.267 DEBUG: Extract sonar-scanner-api-batch in temp...
13:12:58.285 DEBUG: Get bootstrap index...
13:12:58.285 DEBUG: Download: http://localhost:9000/batch/index
13:12:58.355 DEBUG: Get bootstrap completed
13:12:58.355 DEBUG: Create isolated classloader...
13:12:58.374 DEBUG: Start temp cleaning...
13:12:58.389 DEBUG: Temp cleaning done
13:12:58.391 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
13:12:58.406 DEBUG: Execution start
13:12:58.675 DEBUG: Publish global mode
13:12:58.791 INFO: Load global settings
13:12:58.845 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/settings/values.protobuf | time=43ms
13:12:58.866 INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=76ms
13:12:58.880 INFO: User cache: C:\Users\p.das.purkayastha\.sonar\cache
13:12:59.126 INFO: Load plugins index
13:12:59.157 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/deploy/plugins/index.txt | time=14ms
13:12:59.164 INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=38ms
13:12:59.168 DEBUG: Load plugins
13:12:59.199 DEBUG: Load plugins (done) | time=31ms
13:12:59.221 DEBUG: API compatibility mode is enabled on plugin Git [scmgit] (built with API lower than 5.2)
13:12:59.226 DEBUG: API compatibility mode is enabled on plugin SVN [scmsvn] (built with API lower than 5.2)
13:12:59.363 DEBUG: Plugins:
13:12:59.364 DEBUG:   * C# 5.10.1.1411 (csharp)
13:12:59.365 DEBUG:   * Python 1.7.0.1195 (python)
13:12:59.365 DEBUG:   * SonarJava 4.9.0.9858 (java)
13:12:59.384 DEBUG:   * Flex 2.3 (flex)
13:12:59.386 DEBUG:   * Git 1.2 (scmgit)
13:12:59.386 DEBUG:   * SonarXML 1.4.2.885 (xml)
13:12:59.386 DEBUG:   * SonarPHP 2.10.0.2087 (php)
13:12:59.411 DEBUG:   * SVN 1.4.0.522 (scmsvn)
13:12:59.413 DEBUG:   * SonarJS 3.0.0.4962 (javascript)
13:12:59.442 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
13:12:59.445 INFO: SonarQube server 6.4.0
13:12:59.446 INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)
13:12:59.446 DEBUG: Work directory: C:\sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778-windows\bin\.scannerwork
13:12:59.470 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
13:12:59.472 DEBUG: Execution execute
13:12:59.805 INFO: Process project properties
13:12:59.806 DEBUG: Process project properties (done) | time=1ms
13:12:59.934 INFO: Load project repositories
13:12:59.965 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/batch/project.protobuf?key=xml%3ATesting_INFA_XMLs_Folder_Name | time=27ms
13:13:00.016 INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=82ms
13:13:00.123 DEBUG: Available languages:
13:13:00.126 DEBUG:   * C# => "cs"
13:13:00.133 DEBUG:   * Python => "py"
13:13:00.136 DEBUG:   * Java => "java"
13:13:00.148 DEBUG:   * Flex => "flex"
13:13:00.151 DEBUG:   * XML => "xml"
13:13:00.161 DEBUG:   * PHP => "php"
13:13:00.166 DEBUG:   * JavaScript => "js"
13:13:00.189 INFO: Load quality profiles
13:13:00.230 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/qualityprofiles/search.protobuf?projectKey=xml%3ATesting_INFA_XMLs_Folder_Name | time=36ms
13:13:00.238 INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=49ms
13:13:00.250 INFO: Load active rules
13:13:00.366 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AVzv5-V5wdA6ze3S2GhG&p=1&ps=500 | time=115ms
13:13:00.645 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AVzv5-cwwdA6ze3S2Gjn&p=1&ps=500 | time=215ms
13:13:00.753 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AVzv5-kLwdA6ze3S2Gn3&p=1&ps=500 | time=63ms
13:13:00.799 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AVzwAeH1wdA6ze3S2Gt1&p=1&ps=500 | time=30ms
13:13:00.877 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AVzv5-tUwdA6ze3S2Gs0&p=1&ps=500 | time=68ms
13:13:00.956 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AVzv5-m6wdA6ze3S2GpZ&p=1&ps=500 | time=60ms
13:13:01.031 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AVzv5-l0wdA6ze3S2Go2&p=1&ps=500 | time=49ms
13:13:01.063 INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=813ms
13:13:01.066 INFO: Load metrics repository
13:13:01.086 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/metrics/search?f=name,description,direction,qualitative,custom&ps=500&p=1 | time=18ms
13:13:01.144 INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=78ms
13:13:01.181 WARN: SCM provider autodetection failed. No SCM provider claims to support this project. Please use sonar.scm.provider to define SCM of your project.
13:13:01.186 INFO: Publish mode
13:13:01.186 INFO: Project key: xml:Testing_INFA_XMLs_Folder_Name
13:13:01.186 DEBUG: Start recursive analysis of project modules
13:13:01.211 INFO: -------------  Scan INFA_XML_VAL
13:13:01.339 INFO: Load server rules
13:13:01.496 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/rules/list.protobuf | time=156ms
13:13:01.516 INFO: Load server rules (done) | time=177ms
13:13:01.618 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language C# were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.cs : **/*.cs
13:13:01.624 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Python were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.py : **/*.py
13:13:01.632 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Java were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.java : **/*.java,**/*.jav
13:13:01.641 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Flex were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.flex : **/*.as
13:13:01.649 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language XML were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.xml : **/*.xml,**/*.xsd,**/*.xsl
13:13:01.664 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language PHP were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.php : **/*.php,**/*.php3,**/*.php4,**/*.php5,**/*.phtml,**/*.inc
13:13:01.674 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language JavaScript were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.js : **/*.js
13:13:01.761 DEBUG: Initializers : GenericCoverageSensor
13:13:01.764 INFO: Initializer GenericCoverageSensor
13:13:01.766 INFO: Initializer GenericCoverageSensor (done) | time=2ms
13:13:01.779 INFO: Base dir: C:\sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778-windows\bin
13:13:01.783 INFO: Working dir: C:\sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778-windows\bin\.scannerwork
13:13:01.793 INFO: Source paths: .
13:13:01.798 INFO: Source encoding: windows-1252, default locale: en_US
13:13:01.808 INFO: Index files
13:13:01.835 DEBUG: 'sonar-scanner-debug.bat' indexed with language 'null'
13:13:01.838 DEBUG: 's_m_GW_FDR_SOI_ST_SPCIF_PL.XML' indexed with language 'xml'
13:13:01.837 DEBUG: 'sonar-scanner.bat' indexed with language 'null'
13:13:01.847 DEBUG: 's_m_REF_TFADDTNL_RES_TYPE_LOAD.XML' indexed with language 'xml'
13:13:01.862 INFO: 4 files indexed
13:13:01.873 INFO: Quality profile for xml: Testing INFA XMLs
13:13:02.651 DEBUG: 'Generic Coverage Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
13:13:02.654 DEBUG: 'Generic Test Executions Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
13:13:02.667 DEBUG: 'C#' skipped because there is no related file in current project
13:13:02.671 DEBUG: 'C# Unit Tests Coverage Report Import' skipped because there is no related file in current project
13:13:02.680 DEBUG: 'C# Integration Tests Coverage Report Import' skipped because there is no related file in current project
13:13:02.690 DEBUG: 'C# Unit Test Results Import' skipped because there is no related file in current project
13:13:02.695 DEBUG: 'Python Squid Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
13:13:02.713 DEBUG: 'SurefireSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
13:13:02.716 DEBUG: 'JaCoCoSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
13:13:02.716 DEBUG: 'JavaSquidSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
13:13:02.735 DEBUG: 'Flex' skipped because there is no related file in current project
13:13:02.746 DEBUG: 'Flex Cobertura' skipped because there is no related file in current project
13:13:02.746 DEBUG: 'PHP sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
13:13:02.762 DEBUG: 'JavaScript Squid Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
13:13:02.773 DEBUG: 'Generic Coverage Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
13:13:02.779 DEBUG: 'Generic Test Executions Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
13:13:02.784 DEBUG: 'C#' skipped because there is no related file in current project
13:13:02.789 DEBUG: 'C# Unit Tests Coverage Report Import' skipped because there is no related file in current project
13:13:02.802 DEBUG: 'C# Integration Tests Coverage Report Import' skipped because there is no related file in current project
13:13:02.807 DEBUG: 'C# Unit Test Results Import' skipped because there is no related file in current project
13:13:02.820 DEBUG: 'Python Squid Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
13:13:02.823 DEBUG: 'SurefireSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
13:13:02.837 DEBUG: 'JaCoCoSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
13:13:02.841 DEBUG: 'JavaSquidSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
13:13:02.855 DEBUG: 'Flex' skipped because there is no related file in current project
13:13:02.856 DEBUG: 'Flex Cobertura' skipped because there is no related file in current project
13:13:02.872 DEBUG: 'PHP sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
13:13:02.878 DEBUG: 'JavaScript Squid Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
13:13:02.895 DEBUG: Sensors : SonarJavaXmlFileSensor -> XML Sensor -> Analyzer for "php.ini" files -> Zero Coverage Sensor -> CPD Block Indexer
13:13:02.902 INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java]
13:13:02.904 INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=2ms
13:13:02.917 INFO: Sensor XML Sensor [xml]
13:13:03.096 DEBUG: 's_m_GW_FDR_SOI_ST_SPCIF_PL.XML' generated metadata  with charset 'windows-1252'
13:13:03.141 DEBUG: Count lines in C:/sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778-windows/bin/s_m_GW_FDR_SOI_ST_SPCIF_PL.XML
13:13:04.304 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
13:13:04.307 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
13:13:04.308 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
13:13:04.322 INFO: Total time: 6.565s
13:13:04.474 INFO: Final Memory: 47M/361M
13:13:04.476 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
13:13:04.485 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: Unable to analyse file C:/sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778-windows/bin/s_m_GW_FDR_SOI_ST_SPCIF_PL.XML
        at org.sonar.plugins.xml.XmlSensor.processException(XmlSensor.java:193)
        at org.sonar.plugins.xml.XmlSensor.execute(XmlSensor.java:156)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
        at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:87)
        at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:81)
        at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:67)
        at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:75)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:178)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:259)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:254)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:243)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
        at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
        at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:118)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:117)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.sonar.plugins.xml.XmlSensor.saveIssue(XmlSensor.java:126)
        at org.sonar.plugins.xml.XmlSensor.runChecks(XmlSensor.java:102)
        at org.sonar.plugins.xml.XmlSensor.execute(XmlSensor.java:152)
        ... 31 more
13:13:04.805 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
13:13:04.818 DEBUG: Execution stop
```

Comment: Let me know if you need the complete debug details.

Comment: It would easier to help you if you provided your XPath expression, the complete logs, and the version of the Sonar XML plugin you're using (you can find it in the Update Center part of the SonarQube administration).

Comment: Added below the log as it was not getting added in the comment

Comment: Version: SonarXML 1.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARXML-61) and it will be fixed in the upcoming version of SonarXML (1.4.3).

Comment: is the sonarXML 1.4.3 available

Comment: Yes it is: https://www.sonarsource.com/resources/product-news/news.html#sonarxml-143